# Unable to connect to ethernet Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: networking, 16.04

I am able to connect to my network via a wireless drive, but I am not able to connect via Ethernet.

I have tried several of the suggestions.

when I run ifconfig I get:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:9d:ec:eb  
      inet6 addr: fe80::385c:c39b:3398:64f4/64 Scope:Link
      UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
      RX packets:1 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:25 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
      RX bytes:212 (212.0 B)  TX bytes:4549 (4.5 KB)
      Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

 lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
      inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
      inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
      UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
      RX packets:11184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
      TX packets:11184 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
      collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
      RX bytes:1022767 (1.0 MB)  TX bytes:1022767 (1.0 MB)
```

On WiFi:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 44:8a:5b:9d:ec:eb  
          UP BROADCAST MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:4 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:53 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:538 (538.0 B)  TX bytes:7852 (7.8 KB)
          Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:957 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1 
          RX bytes:78347 (78.3 KB)  TX bytes:78347 (78.3 KB)

wlan0     Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0f:60:01:e9:0b  
          inet addr:10.0.0.16  Bcast:10.0.0.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::20f:60ff:fe01:e90b/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:2357 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2256 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:1919052 (1.9 MB)  TX bytes:318893 (318.8 KB)
```

Suggestions?

`dhclient -v eth0` returns:

```
No DHCPOFFERS received. No working leases in persistent database - sleeping.
```

'ifconig' returned new:

```
eth0:avahi Link encap:Ethernet HWaddr 44:8a:5b:9d:ec:eb inet addr:169.254.12.95 Bcast:169.254.255.255 Mask:255.255.0.0 UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST MTU:1500 Metric:1 Interrupt:20 Memory:f7e00000-f7e20000
```

Comment: Your eth0 is only assigning an ipv6 address. Is this intended / supported? Could you provide the output when connected to the wireless?

Comment: wifi is posted below.

Comment: Yeah, it looks like you are only being assigned an ipv6 ip address with your ethernet. Did you change some settings?

Comment: I didnt change any settings

Comment: Assuming you get IPs automatically run `dhclient -v eth0` and then post output of it and `ifconfig -a`

Comment: @meccooll those output are pasted in the original comment